# How to make a ball roll like cannonbolt in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this ball that i want to move by rolling like a certain alien, with it spinning on its transform.up to change its direction and rolling on its transform.right to move forward and backward. But as it rolls, its up and right transform vector gets messed up.

In the end, i was unable to find a way to allow it to roll without messing up my directions vector. I have no clue as to how to do this. So yeah, please help. ORZ. By the way, i'm not creating a game using the Ben10 franchise. The ball should act like a wheel... a really round and spherical one.

Note: 
I want to use physics in this game. Since, i want it to be able to launch itself off a ramp or something. So, only addforce or addtorque or other relevant functions.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I made a project and uploaded it on my Github. See [this](https://github.com/ehsan-mohammadi/Balance-Ball-Unity3D-Game) link. It might help you.

Comment: I think he is trying to lock the gyroscope axis, like here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pronetis.gyrosphere

Comment: See: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136174/75627

Comment: @DanielPiskorz The movement should be like that but it should be tilting in the direction it is turning to.

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: @DanielPiskorz I'm using Input.GetAxis for rotation and forward/backwards movement. As for jumping, I'm using Input.GetKeyDown.